# Export wishlist as CSV

Tags: magento-1.8, frontend, export, csv

A customer of us has a special need for his site.He wants each customer to be able to download his wishlist as CSV.

Now my question is:

I know how to do that on the back-end for my module using in the controller the function `exportCsvAction()` . Is there anything similar i can do with the front-end? Or if not does Magento has something similar i can use or i should do something like getting the wishlist and add it to a CSV??
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add these to your custom module controller:

```
class Some_Module_IndexController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    //Check if customer logged in
    public function preDispatch()
    {
        parent::preDispatch();
        if (!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->authenticate($this)) {
            $this->setFlag('', self::FLAG_NO_DISPATCH, true);
        }
    }

    public function downloadWishlistAction()
    {
        /**
         * @var $wishlist Mage_Wishlist_Model_Wishlist
         * @var $item Mage_Wishlist_Model_Item
         */
        $wishlist = Mage::getModel('wishlist/wishlist');
        $wishlist = $wishlist->loadByCustomer(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer());
        $items = $wishlist->getItemCollection();

        $data = array(
            'Id',
            'Product Id',
            'Name',
            'Price',
            'Qty',
            'Added',
            'Store',
        );
        $fp = fopen('php://temp', 'r+');
        fputcsv($fp, $data, ',', '"');

        foreach ($items as $item) {
            $data = array(
                'id' => $item->getId(),
                'product_id' => $item->getProductId(),
                'product_name' => $item->getProduct()->getName(),
                'product_price' => $item->getProduct()->getPrice(),
                'qty' => $item->getQty(),
                'added_at' => $item->getAddedAt(),
                'store_name' => Mage::app()->getStore($item->getStoreId())->getName(),
            );
            fputcsv($fp, $data, ',', '"');
        }
        rewind($fp);
        $data = fread($fp, 1048576);
        fclose($fp);

        return $this->_prepareDownloadResponse(
            'MyWishList.csv',
            $data,
            'application/csv'
        );
    }
}
```

And customer can download own wishlist entering `yourdomain.com/module_frontend/index/downloadWishlist`

Comment: I was wondering how _prepareDownloadResponse($fileName, $content, $contentType = 'application/octet-stream',$contentLength = null) is working.That's from the class: param: string|array $content set to null to avoid starting output, $contentLength should be set explicitly in. How else can we set the content? string or array? I' m a little confused..But thanks it works great